# Aria label not read by NVDA in Custom tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

Screen reader not reading the items given in aria-label or  aria-describedby. It only reads the text in label.
I want to add more text to be read by screen reader but not to display in screen

```
              <MFileUpload  id="my-id"
                    label={"Drag and drop a document or browse"}
                    tabIndex="0"
                    aria-label={`Hello elephant `}
                    aria-describedby={'Hello aria-describedby'}
                    role="navigation"
                >
                    {children}
                </MFileUpload>
```

Comment: What is MFileUpload, and what does it do with the `aria-label` prop? Native HTML attributes will not apply to React components unless you use them as props in the component. Additionally, I would consider using visually-hidden text rather than aria-label. See: https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Comment: Please also beware of the difference between `label`, `aria-label` and `aria-description`. The label usually is the visible part which should be used as the one for assistive technology (AT, e.g. screen readers) as well. `aria-label` will provide an alternative name for AT, but [it needs to at least contain the text of the visible label](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/label-in-name.html). `aria-describedby` expects an ID, not a text, and usually provides the relationship for AT between the input and already visible help text or error messages.

Comment: It’s been a while for me: Can you actually pass dashed props in JSX? Or would you need to either wrap them in something, or use camelCase like `ariaLabel`?
In the end, as @Auroratide explained, if the component does not spread additional props down to the native element, this wont help eitherr.